# 2dof mass spring damper system in python, odeint error

Tags: python, scipy

I am a beginner who has just started Python.
I chose to major in mechanical engineering and to program my mechanics calculations by studying Python. And now I am making a 2DOF mass-spring-damper model.
I have found a model in 1DOF on the Internet, and (http://ifcuriousthenlearn.com/blog/2015/06/09/mechanical-vibrations-with-python/) I want to apply this to implement 2DOF.

But an error occurred.

Here is the code and error.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from pylab import plot, xlabel, ylabel, title, legend, figure, subplot
from pylab import cos, pi, arange, sqrt, array

    def MassSpringDamper(state1,state2,t):

    k1=124e3            # spring constant, kN/m
    k2=50e3  
    m1=10               # mass, Kg
    m2=20
    c1=5                # damping coefficient
    c2=3

    # unpack the state vector
    x1,x1d = state1 
    x2,x2d = state2     # displacement,x and velocity x'

    g = 9.8             # metres per second**2

    x1dd = (c1+c2)/m1*x1d-c2/m1*x2d+(k1+k2)/m1*x1-k2/m1*x2-g
    x2dd = -c2/m2*x1d+c2/m2*x2d-k2/m2*x1+k2/m2*x2-g
    return [x1d, x1dd, x2d, x2dd]

state0 = [0.0, 1.2]     # initial conditions [x0 , v0]  [m, m/sec] 
ti = 0.0                # initial time
tf = 4.0                # final time
step = 0.001            # step
t = arange(ti, tf, step)
state1 = odeint(MassSpringDamper, state0, t)
state2 = odeint(MassSpringDamper, state0, t)
x1 = array(state1[:,[0]])
x1d = array(state1[:,[1]])
x2 = array(state2[:,[0]])
x2d = array(state2[:,[1]])
```

Error here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65ty7.jpg)

TypeError: MassSpringDamper() missing 1 required positional argument: 't'

how can i do?

thanks for the reading my question.

Comment: Your function expects two state inputs and you're giving it one.

Comment: You need two 2-element vectors as initial condition. A position and speed for each degree of freedom. You're only passing one. You have to pass two. You're returning a 4-length list; perhaps you need to rewrite your function to expect a single 4-length state input, then pass it a 4-length initial state.

Comment: You might find the example ["Coupled spring-mass system"](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/CoupledSpringMassSystem.html) that I wrote for the SciPy cookbook helpful.